# PHPSESSID: Session Cookie Does Not Contain the “Secure” Attribute

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm running https on the frontend and on the backend of my website but how come i'm not getting the secure flag?

I believe the code is here in these two files: magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/CookieMetadata.php->getSecure()

```
    /**
     * Get HTTP Only flag
     *
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function getHttpOnly()
    {
        return $this->get(self::KEY_HTTP_ONLY);
    }

    /**
     * Get whether the cookie is only available under HTTPS
     *
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function getSecure()
    {
        return $this->get(self::KEY_SECURE);
    }
}
```

magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/SensitiveCookieMetadata.php->getSecure()

```
class SensitiveCookieMetadata extends CookieMetadata
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param array $metadata
     */
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, $metadata = [])
    {
        if (!isset($metadata[self::KEY_HTTP_ONLY])) {
            $metadata[self::KEY_HTTP_ONLY] = true;
        }
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($metadata);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSecure()
    {
        $this->updateSecureValue();
        return $this->get(self::KEY_SECURE);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __toArray()
    {
        $this->updateSecureValue();
        return parent::__toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Update secure value, set it to request setting if it has no explicit value assigned.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function updateSecureValue()
    {
        if (null === $this->get(self::KEY_SECURE)) {
            $this->set(self::KEY_SECURE, $this->request->isSecure());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I've tried a few different things but haven't been able to get it to secure. Help please.

Comment: Whats your code for creating the cookie?

Comment: @JasonK i updated the question with the code that i believe creates the cookie.